# How do I assign elements to the column of a pandas dataframe based on the properties of groups derived from that dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I import pandas and numpy as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

and construct the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha' 
['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],'Beta' : np.NaN})
```

...which gives me this:

```
    Alpha  Beta
0      A   NaN
1      A   NaN
2      A   NaN
3      B   NaN
4      B   NaN
5      B   NaN
6      B   NaN
7      C   NaN
8      C   NaN
9      C   NaN
10     C   NaN
11     C   NaN
```

How do I use pandas to get the following dataframe?

```
df_u = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],'Beta' : [1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3]})
```

i.e. this:

```
   Alpha  Beta
0      A     1
1      A     2
2      A     3
3      B     1
4      B     2
5      B     2
6      B     3
7      C     1
8      C     2
9      C     2
10     C     2
11     C     3
```

Generally speaking what I'm trying to achieve can be described by the following logic:

Suppose we group df by Alpha.

For every group, for every row in the group...

- if the index of the row equals the minimum index of rows in the group, then assign 1 to Beta for that row,
- else if the index of the row equals the maximum index of the rows in the group, then assign 3 to Beta for that row,
- else assign 2 to Beta for that row.

Answer (score 0):

**method 1**

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
mask1=df['Alpha'].ne(df['Alpha'].shift())
mask3=df['Alpha'].ne(df['Alpha'].shift(-1))
mask2=~(mask1|mask3)
cond=[mask1,mask2,mask3]
values=[1,2,3]
df['Beta']=np.select(cond,values)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Alpha  Beta
0      A     1
1      A     2
2      A     3
3      B     1
4      B     2
5      B     2
6      B     3
7      C     1
8      C     2
9      C     2
10     C     2
11     C     3
```

---

**Detail of cond list:**

```
print(mask1)
0      True
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
Name: Alpha, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print(mask2)
0     False
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
Name: Alpha, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print(mask3)
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
Name: Alpha, dtype: bool
```

---

**method 2**

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
def assign_value(x):
    return pd.Series([1]+[2]*(len(x)-2)+[3])
new_df=df.groupby('Alpha').apply(assign_value).rename('Beta').reset_index('Alpha') 
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  Alpha  Beta
0     A     1
1     A     2
2     A     3
0     B     1
1     B     2
2     B     2
3     B     3
0     C     1
1     C     2
2     C     2
3     C     2
4     C     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use duplicated:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated('Alpha', keep='last'), 'Beta'] = 3
df.loc[~df.duplicated('Alpha', keep='first'), 'Beta'] = 1
df['Beta'] = df['Beta'].fillna(2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Alpha  Beta
0      A   1.0
1      A   2.0
2      A   3.0
3      B   1.0
4      B   2.0
5      B   2.0
6      B   3.0
7      C   1.0
8      C   2.0
9      C   2.0
10     C   2.0
11     C   3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that "Alpha" column is sorted you can do it like this

```py
df["Beta"] = 2
df.loc[~(df["Alpha"] == df["Alpha"].shift()), "Beta"] = 1
df.loc[~(df["Alpha"] == df["Alpha"].shift(-1)), "Beta"] = 3
df
```